# How to pass command-line options to Alex in Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, alex

In my current project I have a file `Tokens.x` that needs to be compiled to `Tokens.hs` by Alex.  In my `.cabal` file I have listed `Tokens` in the `other-modules` section and `cabal build` happily creates the file.

However it does so without the -g option that instructs Alex to create a GHC optimized version of the file.  This option represents a 10x speed up in scanning when used with GHC and is also an order of magnitude faster to compile.

How do I tell cabal to included the -g option when compiling using GHC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, with Cabal you can currently only specify program options in the configuration file or via the command line, but not in a `.cabal` file.

There's an open issue about this: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1223

However, looking at the sources for `Cabal`, I find that your particular problem seems to be solved by default. In `Distribution.Simple.PreProcess`, there's:

```
ppAlex :: BuildInfo -> LocalBuildInfo -> PreProcessor
ppAlex _ lbi = pp { platformIndependent = True }
  where pp = standardPP lbi alexProgram (hcFlags hc)
        hc = compilerFlavor (compiler lbi)
        hcFlags GHC = ["-g"]
        hcFlags _ = []
```

This means that if Cabal is used with GHC, then `-g` is automatically passed to Alex when it's being used as a preprocessor.

Comment: I came across this when searching for the same answer for Happy and discover that Cabal also automatically supplies `-a -g -c` to all Happy invocations as recommended by the Happy manual.

Comment: Just for further reference, [here](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/e28abb9ca321b74c82931d23d1e1cc75574ce4b9/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/PreProcess.hs) is the source file where the flags passed to Happy and Alex can be found. As @GabrielGonzalez mentioned, the `-agc` flags are passed automatically.